# System alarm recurrence

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows Phone allows you to create and register system alarms with the ScheduledActionService.  The options for recurrenceType are daily, weekly, etc.

I am trying to get alarms set for specific days.  This is not possible using the recurrenceType enum.  The only way I can see to achieve this is to create an alarm for each day specified.  This way, for a single alarm that is created I will have to create a copy of it on every day I wish it to recur.

The only issue with this is displaying them.  They cannot be given a 'Name' property and so there is no way to logically group these alarms in to a single "master" alarm.

has anyone encountered this issue?  Is there a way to set alarms without using this scheduler service?  I cannot think of a way around this and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only example I'm aware of where someone was in a similar situation resulted in them not using the scheduler at all.
As they required a complex scheduling pattern they instead chose to not use any of the built in functionality but rather to create individual alarms as appropriate. They already had an existing BackgroundAgent and added functionality there to ensure that the next two alarms were always queued up.

Your exact requirements may make this possible.
I'd think carefully about adding an agent just for this though.